# How to log values from enums with the prepocessor to a file

Tags: c, gcc, enums, logging, c-preprocessor

I declare a enum like that:

```
typedef enum message_t {
    mes_no_error    =   0,  // no message sent
    mes_internal    =   1,  // reserved for internals
    mes_start       =   2,  // when main() is executed
    mes_init        =   3,  // when inits in main() are done
    mes_end         =   4,  // when main() returns
    mes_foo,
    mes_bar,
    mes_joe
} message;
```

As this is for a microcontroller which talk to me on the PC, I would like to know the values that are used for mes_foo, mes_bar, mes_joe....

I thought I could use compiler directives like that:

```
#warning "mes_block_01 = " mes_joe
```

and later tee, regex and dump the values to a file when compiling the program. However, gcc just tells me:

```
message.h:63:2: Warnung: #warning "mes_block_01 = " mes_joe
```

with no value, but only the enum name.

Is it somehow possible to log automatically assigned values from enums to a file? Is it somehow possible to show values of constants/defines with the preprocessor or during compile time?

Comment: No answer, but why would you want to do this? The unspecified values will be set according to some standard rule, I think `mes_foo`->5 etc,  another question could answer that. If you depend on them to have specific values, why don't you just set them?

Comment: The enum members serve as name for an (int) message that is sent from a microcontroller to the PC. There is a GUI application that shows me all the messages (in a GtkTreeStore). Because the numbers of the messages are not easy to read for humans, I want to display the names that are used in the enum. I have a dumb data protocol for uC->PC communication, and the messages should be flexible and easy to change. Therefore I wanted dump the enum values somewhere during compile time and dynamically include them in the GUI. Any idea?

Comment: Have you looking into X macros, e.g. http://drdobbs.com/blogs/cpp/228700289?

Comment: The reason you can't do this with the preprocessor is that the preprocessor manipulates the *text* of the source before the compiler proper ever starts working on it. It don't know anything about c---just text.

Comment: @honk Simple but awesome idea! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

According to [K&R](http://cg.inf.unideb.hu/eng/rtornai/Kernighan_Ritchie_Language_C.pdf),

**A.8.4 Enumeration**

> ...
>
> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants of
>   type int, and may appear wherever constants are required. If no
>   enumerations with = appear, then the values of the corresponding
>   constants begin at 0 and increase by 1 as the declaration is read from
>   left to right. An enumerator with = gives the associated identifier
>   the value specified; **subsequent identifiers continue the progression
>   from the assigned value**

So `mes_foo=5`, `mes_bar=6` and `mes_joe=7`. You don't need to do anything at compile time to know these values. Their values are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

See Pavan's answer for how enums behave.

Because they behave like that you should never just initialize some of the enum members. Initialize all or none. Otherwise you might get accidental bugs when writing code like this:

```
typedef enum 
{ 
  BLUE=2, 
  BLACK, 
  WHITE=3, 
  YELLOW=7
} Color_t;

Color_t color = BLACK;

if(color == WHITE)
{
  printf("White");  // will get executed with color == BLACK
}
```

Because of bugs like this one, writing halfways initialized enums like this is banned by MISRA-C:2004, 9.3.

Answer (score 0):

@honk did it. He recognised that I need a semantic connection between enum values and a human readable name that is easy to maintain and parse by a GUI application. I will but

```
#define MESSAGES \
    X(MES_NO_ERROR, 0) \
    X(MES_INTERNAL, 1) \
    X(MES_START, 2)
```

into messages.h and then in the message module just do

```
#define X(a, b) b,
enum messages_t { MESSAGES };
#undef X
```

Thanks!